# How to trigger a iframe callback function in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently working on a project for client,and that client has giving me a widget which resides in an iframe to incorporate within the application.The widget allows a user to search their company database for a customer. When the customer is found a callback function is triggered and a JSON response is returned. The iframe code is stored in a modal, here is the code:

```
<div class="loanModal">
<div class="modal-header">
    <a class="pull-left closeWidget" ng-click="closeWidget()"></a>
</div>
<div class="modal-body" style="padding:0;">
    <iframe id="IFrameSearch" frameborder="0" src="http://domainName/ucs?cbFuncAfterSelect=UCINSelected&cbFuncAfterResult=UCSSearchComplete&cbFuncAfterSave=UCSavingComplete&cbFuncAfterClose=UCAppClosed&app" style="overflow:hidden;max-height:100%;height:auto;min-height:640px;max-height:640px;width:100%;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px;">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

I am using angularjs ui-bootstrap modal for starting the widget. If I placed the callback code in the modal html view, which is this:

```
function UCINSelected(clientObj){
      console.log(clientObj);
}
```

This will get back the JSON object; however I need to get the clientObj in the angularjs ui-bootstrap modal controller so that I can save the information from the JSON object to the application database using angularjs $http service. So how could I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not really clear what you are asking. How to get data from inside iframe?

Comment: @charlietfl. Yes, I'm trying to retrieve data from inside the iframe via regular javascript function to send to angularjs. Essentially, I am trying to retrieve the json object.

Comment: do you have access to code inside iFrame? One way is use postMessage API

Comment: No I don't have access to the code inside the iFrame

Comment: There is no simple solution without a lot more details and you may not be able to access it at all if it is cross domain